# Generating Null columns dynamically in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create some null columns dynamically in a PL/SQL function that returns an SQL query within oracle apex and am having some difficulty doing so.  Here is the code I have so far:

```html
DECLARE
  l_query VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := NVL(:P31_PARTS,'abc123');
  l_cols_arr  apex_t_varchar2;
  counter number(3,1);

BEGIN
    l_cols_arr := apex_string.split(p_str => l_cols, p_sep => ':');
    counter := l_cols_arr.count;   

    l_query := 'SELECT CRITERIA_NAME, ';
    FOR i IN 1..(counter - 1)
    LOOP
        l_query := l_query || 'CAST(NULL AS varchar2(4000)) AS "'||l_cols_arr(i)||'", ';
    END LOOP;
    l_query := l_query || 'CAST(NULL AS varchar2(4000)) AS "'||l_cols_arr(counter)||'" FROM TABLE_VIEW';

    return l_query;
END;
```

In its current state the code validates but at run time, loading the page gives me the following error:

```
Error during rendering of region "Data Input.2".
```

In my attempts to troubleshoot the problem I outputed the contents of `:P31_Parts` into a display only page item and it displays the following string:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEtJF.png)

After copying the contents of the page item and hardcoding it into `l_cols` the code runs and executes exactly as I'd like it to.  I'm not too familiar with how oracle stores data and how that differs from how it displays it in a page item, but if it helps `:P31_PARTS` is a colon delimited string generated from a checkbox group on a different page in the application.

If anyone is confused by the explanation feel free to ask and I'll do my best to clear up any questions.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick test with the EMP dataset and this works fine:

- Region Type: Classic Report
- PL/SQL Function Body:

```
DECLARE
  l_query VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := NVL(:P146_COLS,'EMPNO');
  l_cols_arr  apex_t_varchar2;
  
BEGIN
  l_cols_arr := apex_string.split(p_str => l_cols, p_sep => ':');
  l_query := 'SELECT ';
  FOR i IN 1..l_cols_arr.count
  LOOP
    l_query := l_query||' CAST(NULL AS varchar2(4000)) AS "'||l_cols_arr(i)||'", ';
    APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P146_COL'||i,l_cols_arr(i));
  END LOOP;
  l_query := RTRIM(l_query,', ')||' FROM EMP';
  apex_debug.info(
    p_message => l_query);
  RETURN l_query;
END;
```

- Items to submit: `P146_COLS`
- Use Generic Column Names: Checked
- Generic Column Count: 10

Note that you should run the page in debug and check the debug logs.You can also use the API `apex_debug` to log your own messages in the debug logs as shown in the example code.

UPDATE:
It's possible to make the column headers dynamic as well. In the page, create a number of page items `P146_COL1,P146_COL2,...`. Then set the column headers of the generic colums to `&P146_COL1!HTML.` for COL01, `&P146_COL2!HTML.` for COL02, etc. In the source code, set the values for each of the column header page items.

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for your response but I noticed a few problems when trying it.  When using my own table the code compiled and the page ran with no errors in the debug log but the table isn't there as if it was a hidden region.  When the emp table it works fine.  I tried it with an interactive report (which is what I want in the end, sorry for not specifying) I get `ORA-00904 "D"."CABLEPARTS":invalid identifier`

Comment: Well... as I stated in my answer (last line) - debug debug and debug... it's your environment, I don't have access to it so I can't check the debug logs but that is where I would start...

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without using the generic column names in the classic report?

Comment: I believe generic columns are needed if the number of columns can vary. But what you can do is use page items as column headers and set those in the pl/sql code that generates the query. See my updated answer. Remember to mark the question as answered - best way to say thanks.

Comment: And I'm assuming you can't do generic column stuff in an interactive grid or make a classic report editable?

Comment: I don't think you can - sorry.